# How can i move bootstrap row div to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need move bootstrap elements of row `div` to the bottom of the page and make it responsive.
I tried add position:absolute to row class, but didn't worked so well.

How can i do this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz93cgxd/)

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Did you mean make a row fixed at bottom?

Comment: Can you add some code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: Yes. The row must be fixed at the bottom. Intro, work, about, contacts elements must be at the bottom of the page. I uplouaded image how it looks now http://postimg.org/image/8oejmc0it/.

Comment: include this css will may solve issue  #bottom-list{ position : absolute; bottom : 0; }

Comment: But then i change to  #bottom-list{ position : absolute; bottom : 0; } all .container elements disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to absolutely position the element with the id bottom-list.

In order to make it go to the bottom of the page add

```
bottom:0;
```

to the selector.

In this way you specify the offset of the absolutely positioned element from the bottom of the containing element.

If however in your layout one of the parent elements has a CSS property

```
position: relative;
```

then this may work differently.

Hence I suggest the outermost container element i.e. `.container` must be absolutely positioned with `bottom:0;`

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fz93cgxd/4/

Comment: But then i change to #bottom-list{ position : absolute; bottom : 0; } all .container elements disappear.

Comment: If this is for your footer I suggest you maintain a separate <div>..</div> for it or use the <footer> ... </footer> element. Please could you tell me a little more about what exactly are you using this for, and preferably provide a mockup of the structure you are expecting, or a reference point?

Comment: I'll give my all code what i done so far https://jsfiddle.net/bjrbLepa/ and image how it look like http://postimg.org/image/8oejmc0it/. Maybe it helps more to find problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the fiddle, adding the css #bottom-list{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
does get your #bottom-list at the bottom of the page, is responsive, and the contents of .container i.e. the button and the logo are still there
updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjrbLepa/1/

Comment: Thanks, but when i add #bottom-list{position:absolute; bottom:0;} i get this  http://s30.postimg.org/dw3cvgkip/Be_pavadinimo.jpg. What happend? How to fix that?

Comment: Well that is really strange, not sure about that, however I notice that you have #bottom-list within a section with an id header. Try moving that out of the section and then add the CSS.
I have done it in this edit: https://jsfiddle.net/bjrbLepa/2/
I hope this works, I'm pretty much out of ideas now :P

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a **Responive** bootstrap `navbar` fixed on bottom you may need to start with Bootstrap navbar itself then add your custom style on it 
like

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-justified fixed-bootm navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">01 INTRO <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">02 WORK</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">03 ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">04 CONTACTS</a></li>
        
   
          </ul>

      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**Note:** all those code is with bootstrap style I didn't write a single line of CSS

Now you can start adding your custom styles